# Do I have to play Persona games in order?

Tags: persona-series

Should I go through 1 to 5 or just have my fun with 4 and 5 only? Would I miss anything?

Comment: "Miss anything" how? Story-wise? Gameplay-wise? You would miss the first three games if you'd only play 4 and 5, but I'm guessing you know that :)

Comment: Even if its not explained very deep, I think its easy to figure out he's talking about story wise. Its always a thing when there is a numbered entry in a franchise if you will need to see what comes before to be able to understand what is happening in this new entry, or is it just the same concepts but a different story altogether. Like Can you sit down and watch Harry Potter 6 and get everything? Or will you be confused because you dont know what happened in 1-5? But you can sit down in front of Final Fantasy 15 without ever touching 1-14 and you will still be able to follow the plot.

Comment: On terms of gameplay/mechanics, games that will not tutorial you on all the things are very rare anyways.

Comment: Yes, that and I also meant like easter eggs or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persona is like the Final Fantasy series.

Mechanics are the same, but except that, the story is completely different from game to game (except for P5: The Strikers, that is a follow up to Persona 5).

The most you will get is a quick reference to an older persona, like the protagonists of P4 going on a student visit to the school of P3.

Except if you look really deep in the lore there is not even an overarching story linking the games together. You can start with whatever Persona game you want, and you will not be lost with them referring to what happened in the previous game. I personally started with 5 with no problems. Played 4 later.

Another thing to note about the Persona Series, they seem to love to make a remake a few years after the original game, that is basically a retelling of the same story with some added components, an additional character and some QoL adjustments. So there is P3 and P3 FES, P4 and P4 Golden, P5 and P5 The Royale, that basically tell the same story just with some differences in gameplay and a few minor differences in how the story goes.

The basic things that link the Persona games together: You play a highschooler in Japan, that usually just transfered to a new school. You and the friends you make will become in contact with another world where you can use the power of personas to fight monsters. Thats pretty much it.

Comment: It's worth noting that Persona 5 Royals is an expansion of Persona 5, meaning that when you start playing P5 Royals, you go through P5 and then directly into P5 Royals. This is important to note because P5 Strikers takes place after the events of Persona 5, but before the events that take place during P5 Royals.

Comment: Havent played the royale yet but I'm pretty sure you don't have P5 abridged and then the Royale. You basically play P5 completely again (with a few differences in how the story goes, like a retelling) and then get a bonus few dungeon/months at the end.

Comment: Those things you've mentioned take (in story) place after the summer vacation. Strikers takes place through the summer vacation

Comment: Ah I tought it was at the end. Makes more sense now that I think about it. So I guess the extra dungeon is after the Alien one but before the Casino? (Keeping it spoiler free) Also explains how strikers has a story because the true ending of P5 doesn't leave much place for a sequel.

Comment: That I do not know, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ohh, so Strikers is a different timeline too. Thanks, I had no idea. I thought it's kind of a spinoff.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are willing to be surprised at the jump in graphics from ps4.
The older versions have completely different characters in different worlds, while the premise remains the same. There are some different quirks and lore but the older versions are limited due to their console capacity.

However if you are itching for more franchise like story then go ahead.

there's also a continuation of ps5 coming as a small fighter game, however the release date is a mess

Comment: So it's like the Final Fantasy series? Just a bunch of mostly unrelated games in terms of story, mechanics and setting?

Comment: Yeah when I started playing P4 Golden on steam I had a small 'whoa wtf' moment. Then I remembered: This is a PSP game.